# Gauss Green Formula for Parametric Regions

Tags: parametric, gaussian-integral

I'm currently trying to understand the reasoning for an output that was produced using Gauss Green on Parametric Regions.

Say `f(x,y) = 3-x+y` and `g(x,y) = 3-x`. These functions plot surfaces above the region parameterized as `x[t_] = Cos[t] (1 - Cos[t])` & `y[t_] = Sin[t] (1 - Cos[t])` . When I used Gauss Green i obtained a value of `18.0642` for both `f(x,y)` & `g(x,y)`. The only major difference between `f(x,y)` & `g(x,y)` is the exclusion of `y` in `g(x,y) = 3-x`. Although they are both above the same parameterized region, how do they both produce the same value when using Gauss-Green? What am I missing here?

Comment: The formula for $y(t)$ is odd-symmetric (since it's an odd function times an even function); thus, what would happen when you integrate $y$ over that region?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Since the result is an Odd function then integration of y over the region becomes 0.